# How to get new String[0].class without creating an array?

Tags: java

Is there a way to write the Java class for String arrays (or arrays for another class, for that matter) as a literal without creating an array object? The only Java term I can think of that gives the value is `new String[0].getClass()` which is creating a pointless array of length 0.

(BTW: I know that's cheap and I could put that in a static final, but I am curious whether there is another way.)

Comment: @ElliottFrisch no it's not, he's creating a new array and taking its class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this:

```
Class<String[]> cls = String[].class;
```

Answer (score 2):

`String[].class` should do for you.